# Multiply floats inside subsublists as values in a dictionary [edited]

Tags: python, list

Say I have:

```
worksheet={
"a":[[1.0],[2.0, 3.0]],
"b":[[4.0]]
}
```

My aim is to multiply each value inside subsublists by a single value, -keeping the same structure- let's say *10, for instance, so I need:

```
worksheet={
"a":[[10.0],[20.0, 30.0]],
"b":[[40.0]]
}
```

Every dict value will always contain a list with one or more sublists.
Every sublist will always contain at -least- a float. No empty lists (no empty dict values). I cannot use Pandas or Numpy.

Comment: every single value in all sublists will by multiplied by the same value. In other words, all the numbers will by multiplied by one number. In the example: (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) are multiplied by 10.0

Comment: Why does the title say "Multiply keys"? You're just multiplying the elements of the lists, not the keys.

Comment: @Barmar You are absolutely right. I edited the title, hopefully it will help others in the same case. Thank you very much for the advise. My fault.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
worksheet = {'a': [[1.0], [2.0, 3.0]], 'b': [[4.0]]}
new_worksheet = {a:[[c*10 for c in i] for i in b] for a, b in worksheet.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [[10.0], [20.0, 30.0]], 'b': [[40.0]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more readable solution would be using regular `for-loops`

```
for key in worksheet:
    for list in worksheet[key]:
        for sublist in list_:
            for index, value in enumerate(sublist):
                sublist[index] = value * 10
```

even more readable if you use `map` instead of last `for`

```
def multiply(val):
    return val * 10

# ...
for sublist in list_:
    sublist = map(multiply, sublist)  # Note enumerate isnt necessary
```

After it you can easily change it to a more efficient form, using list comprehension:

```
{key: [[value * 10 for value in sublist] for sublist in list_] for key, list in worksheet.items()}
```

Alternatively, you can use `numpy` that support things such as:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr *= 10
```

Comment: Never use the default keywords `dict`, `list` in the program

Comment: Thank you very much @leoschet. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: True, @kvmahesh I had a huge issue using list as a variable. The 3D program Im currently using literally stopped working, i spent hours and hours until I finally realized I changed the list() function by a value... oMG... i'll never ever forget that lesson...